# How do I get a js countdown timer to trigger an event in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timer

I am building a Ruby on Rails app that lets a user create a workout for various durations (i.e. 30 minutes). A workout has_many exercises. Each exercise has a duration (i.e. 30 seconds). I want the workout to loop through a random array of exercises until the timer runs out.

I am trying to get an event to trigger when the timer (in JS) reaches 00:00 - so when the exercise reaches 0 seconds, it renders a new exercise and it's corresponding new countdown.
When the workout.duration = 0, redirect to root_path.

I have the basic app up here: https://morning-garden-55692.herokuapp.com/workouts/3

This all is called from the WorkoutsController and takes place in the Workout#show view.

This is the ruby in the show view:

```
<% @exercises.each do |ex| %>
    <%= ex.name %> <br><br> <div id="exclock"> <span class="hours"></span> :
    <span class="minutes"></span> :
    <span class="seconds"></span>
```

This is the js that runs the clock:

```
<script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var timeInSeconds = <% @exercises.each do |ex| %>
    <%= ex.duration %>; <% end %>
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInSeconds*1000);
initializeClock('exclock', deadline);
</script>
```

In the workouts controller:

```
def show
        @exercises = Exercise.limit(1).order("RANDOM()")

    end
```

I think in the js I need to just include some

```
until: +Exercise.duration == 0, onExpiry: nextEx
```

Any help in triggering a redirect upon expiry or rendering another exercise?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the page with javascript by assigning a new url to `window.location`:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/path-to-exercise";
```

If you are looking to reload the whole page for the next exercise you can just do this when your timer runs out.

If you are looking to replace an element on the page to load the next exercise you can [fire off an XHR](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) when your timer ends to retrieve the new content and then [place it into the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) or [replace an existing element](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-replacement/).